# print all possible routes of a conditional binary tree by python3

Tags: python-3.x

I want to print a conditioned binary tree.
Take an example of five different lists a b c d e:

```
1
2, 4
3, 5, 7
6, 8
9
```

The condition is that the following number must be larger than the previous number, so printing 1, 4, 3, 6, 9 is wrong.
The desired result is:

```
1, 2, 3, 6, 9
1, 2, 5, 6, 9
1, 4, 5, 8, 9
1, 4, 7, 8, 9
```

How to get those lists by python3?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Can share the code showing what you've tried so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.